# How to create a desktop application to mimic what I've already written in PHP?

Tags: java, php, fpdf

just looking for a point in the correct direction..

So I've developed a little application on the back end of our websites that allows the girls in our office to send out letter-headed PDF quotations to our potential clients via email.

I've done this using a simple `HTML form`, the `FPDF class`, and the php function `mail()`

It works a treat, but I'd like to take it a step further and create a desktop application so that the girls don't have to go through the login section of the website to access this functionality.

I'm thinking Java?

Would this be a difficult mission someone who has only had web-developing experience?

It would only be the smallest/simplest of applications.

Thanks for any input :)

Comment: `girls don't have to go through the login section ` Huh? The reason seems awfully weak to me. Do these girls use a browser without "remember me" feature? Or thousands other ways to auto login would be whatever simpler than creating another application from scratch

Comment: Possibly related: https://mozillalabs.com/prism/

Comment: That's a very good point actually :) My question was more aimed towards finding out just how difficult it would be though, not whether or not it was a good idea ;p Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wouldn't be difficult job to mimic your app to java desktop app that can be `Java Swing APP`. you just need some practice on `swing`. As you are doing in `php` that is `creating PDF and mailing it`. This task can easily be done in java swing by using `Java Mail API` for emailing  and `IText` for pdf generation.

For reference you can read following links:

- http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial
- http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/
- http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html
- http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/index.html
- http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/generate-pdf-file-in-java-using-itext-jar.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an advice.

Since you have already developed something that works over web, reuse it.

1. Convert the PDF converter into a service to upload and retrieve file. This service should return a `token_id` that can be used later to download the converted files.
2. Write a Java app using Swing that merely uses this web service. The logic in this application should be 
   (a) browse file from computer, 
   (b) Use web-service upload URL to upload the file and rec/eive appropriate response like `upload_token_id` and status uploaded/converted/failed, 
   (c) the Java app, should be able to use this token to download the converted file.

You may need to look into [this](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-multipart-post-method-for-uploading.html) for help related to uploading the file

Comment: wow! wondering why downvoted? Isn't consistency of result and one application for one purpose have any value!